# Read from AWS Redshift using Databricks (and Apache Spark)

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-redshift, databricks

I'm trying to execute SQL SELECT command using Databricks with AWS Redshift.

I went through https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift README and configure:

- **Spark driver to Redshift** - I'm passing `user` and `password` options
- **Spark to S3** - I've mount AWS S3 using `dbfs` mount.
- **Redshift to S3** - I'm passing `temporary_aws_access_key_id`, `temporary_aws_secret_access_key`, `temporary_aws_session_token`

**NOTE** This is a kind of Proof of Concept so I'm ignoring all security details like encryptions.

### Below configuration I used in my Databricks Notebook:

```py
%python

# Read data from a table
df = spark.read \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://<REDSHIFT_URL>:<DB_PORT>/<DB_NAME>") \
  .option("temporary_aws_access_key_id", "XXX") \
  .option("temporary_aws_secret_access_key","XXX") \
  .option("temporary_aws_session_token", "XXX") \
  .option("user", "XXX") \
  .option("password", "XXX") \
  .option("tempdir", "dbfs:/mnt/result_bucket/...") \
  .option("query", "SELECT * FROM users") \
  .load()

# display(df) #SQL Exception
```

Result:

[image: Dataframe as a result]

But when I would uncomment the last line and try to see SQL SELECT results:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at com.databricks.spark.redshift.JDBCWrapper.executeInterruptibly(RedshiftJDBCWrapper.scala:223)
    at com.databricks.spark.redshift.JDBCWrapper.executeInterruptibly(RedshiftJDBCWrapper.scala:197)
    at com.databricks.spark.redshift.RedshiftRelation.$anonfun$getRDDFromS3$1(RedshiftRelation.scala:212)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:377)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:363)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.SparkDatabricksProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:34)
    at com.databricks.spark.redshift.RedshiftRelation.getRDDFromS3(RedshiftRelation.scala:212)
    at com.databricks.spark.redshift.RedshiftRelation.buildScan(RedshiftRelation.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$.$anonfun$apply$3(DataSourceStrategy.scala:426)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$.$anonfun$pruneFilterProject$1(DataSourceStrategy.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$.pruneFilterProjectRaw(DataSourceStrategy.scala:538)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$.pruneFilterProject(DataSourceStrategy.scala:459)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:426)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.$anonfun$plan$2(QueryPlanner.scala:69)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.$anonfun$plan$1(QueryPlanner.scala:69)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:484)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:490)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:489)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkStrategies.plan(SparkStrategies.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.$anonfun$plan$4(QueryPlanner.scala:85)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$foldLeft$1(TraversableOnce.scala:162)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$foldLeft$1$adapted(TraversableOnce.scala:162)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:162)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft$(TraversableOnce.scala:160)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1429)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.$anonfun$plan$3(QueryPlanner.scala:82)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:484)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:490)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkStrategies.plan(SparkStrategies.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.createSparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:493)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$sparkPlan$1(QueryExecution.scala:129)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:854)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executedPlan$1(QueryExecution.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:854)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$simpleString$2(QueryExecution.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExplainUtils$.processPlan(ExplainUtils.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.simpleString(QueryExecution.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$QueryExecution$$explainString(QueryExecution.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.explainStringLocal(QueryExecution.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$5(SQLExecution.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:854)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3823)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectResult(Dataset.scala:3031)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.OutputAggregator$.withOutputAggregation0(OutputAggregator.scala:268)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.OutputAggregator$.withOutputAggregation(OutputAggregator.scala:102)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocalBase.generateTableResult(PythonDriverLocalBase.scala:526)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.computeListResultsItem(PythonDriverLocal.scala:672)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocalBase.genListResults(PythonDriverLocalBase.scala:490)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.$anonfun$getResultBufferInternal$1(PythonDriverLocal.scala:727)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.withInterpLock(PythonDriverLocal.scala:608)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.getResultBufferInternal(PythonDriverLocal.scala:687)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.getResultBuffer(DriverLocal.scala:634)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.outputSuccess(PythonDriverLocal.scala:650)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.$anonfun$repl$6(PythonDriverLocal.scala:221)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.withInterpLock(PythonDriverLocal.scala:608)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.repl(PythonDriverLocal.scala:208)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$11(DriverLocal.scala:526)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:266)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:261)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:258)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:50)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:305)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:297)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:50)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:503)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$1(DriverWrapper.scala:689)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:681)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:522)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:634)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:427)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:370)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:221)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: UNLOAD destination is not supported. (Hint: only S3 based unload is allowed)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2477)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2190)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:300)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:169)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.execute(PgPreparedStatement.java:158)
    at com.databricks.spark.redshift.JDBCWrapper.$anonfun$executeInterruptibly$1(RedshiftJDBCWrapper.scala:197)
    at com.databricks.spark.redshift.JDBCWrapper.$anonfun$executeInterruptibly$1$adapted(RedshiftJDBCWrapper.scala:197)
    at com.databricks.spark.redshift.JDBCWrapper.$anonfun$executeInterruptibly$2(RedshiftJDBCWrapper.scala:215)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)
    at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

### More details:

Databricks Runtime Version:
`9.1 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.1.2, Scala 2.12)`

I've tried the same with JDBC redshift Driver (using URL prefix `jdbc:redshift`)
Then I had to install `com.github.databricks:spark-redshift_2.11:master-SNAPSHOT` to my Databricks Cluster Libraries.
The result was the same.

Data inside Redshift (sample data created by AWS):
[image: AWS Redshift Data]

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several tries, I figure out the solution.

- I deleted temporary keys
- I used `forward_spark_s3_credentials`
- I attached IAM Role to the EC2's (cluster)
- I used `s3a` path instead mounted `dbfs` directory
- Update the cluster's libraries:

  - I used `RedshiftJDBC42_no_awssdk_1_2_55_1083.jar`
  - and deleted `com.github.databricks:spark-redshift_2.11:master-SNAPSHOT`.

Final configuration:

```
df = spark.read \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://<REDSHIFT_URL>:<DB_PORT>/<DB_NAME>") \
  .option("forward_spark_s3_credentials", "true") \
  .option("user", "XXX") \
  .option("password", "XXX") \
  .option("tempdir", "s3a://<MY_S3_BUCKET>/...") \
  .option("query", "SELECT userid, username FROM users") \
  .load()

display(df)
```

Libraries set up in the cluster:
(Probably only Redshift JDBC driver is needed. I also added libs from AWS bundle (which can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/jdbc20-download-driver.html)

[image: Databrisck cluster configuration]

The final code will be [on my GitHub](https://github.com/pgrabarczyk/databricks-sample/blob/master/Notebooks/Task_4_Change_Data_Capture.py).

Comment: this was very helpful.  The next error I got was databricks / spark complaining about mismatched regions.  Adding 

.option("awsregion", "us-west-2")

will get you past the error.  Change region name as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @pgrabarczyk seems to be consistent with online documentation from Databricks found here (and served me well): https://docs.databricks.com/en/connect/external-systems/amazon-redshift.html

However, having S3 write-access isn't possible for some of my colleagues, so here's an alternate way to fetch data which still uses Databricks' provided drivers:

```
def pull_rs(qry):
  ##########credentials
  host = 'foo.bar.fubar.com'
  port = 5439
  db = 'your_db'
  user = 'your_username'
  pw = 'your_pw'
  ##########credentials

  url = f'jdbc:redshift://{host}:{port}/{db}?ssl=true' ##the SSL statement was required to make my code work
  
  return (spark
        .read 
        .format("redshift")
        .option("url", url)
        .option("user", user)
        .option("password", pw)
        .option("query", qry)
        .load()
      )

#make your calls:
qry = """
      SELECT 
        * 
      FROM 
        your_schema.your_tablename 
      limit 1000
      """
df = pull_rs(qry)

display(df)
```

Alternatively, there's a robust library called redshift-connector found here: https://pypi.org/project/redshift-connector/

It allows for a cursor that can do lots of things, including execution of redshift stored procedures.

Answer (score -1):

one of the errors could be in option('url'). it should be jdbc:redshift not jdbc:postgresql, use redshift and re-try

Comment: I've tried both drivers. The result is the same.